# requestFeature() must be called before adding content error while implementing DatePicker in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

This particular error message is popular on SO and the web but I still can't find a solution from any of the suggested ones to work for me.

Am trying to add a DatePicker to my fragment, which gets fired when a button is clicked.But this error keeps popping up. This is the Fragment class am using:

```
public class MyFragment extends DialogFragment implements 
                     DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

Context context;


@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    //Use the current date as the default value for the picker
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //Create a new instance of datepicker and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

}
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {


}



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 

                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);

    Button reminderButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dueDateButton);
    reminderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyFragment();
            dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    });

    context = getActivity(); 


    return rootView;
}

}
```

This Fragment handles one of the views in a tabbed activity. I have tried adding:

```
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

just before:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newdebt_layout, container, false);
```

with no luck.
I have also tried adding this:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

right before the `setContentView()` method in the activity where this fragment is embedded with no luck also.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939814/android-util-androidruntimeexception-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-add), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250149/requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273273/how-to-solve-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content-in-android?rq=1) questions and a host of others with no luck.

In the stack trace, no specific line in the code is flagged.

```
05-27 06:17:30.687  23204-23204/com.ojonugwaochalifu.blablabla E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ojonugwaochalifu.blablabla, PID: 23204
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:336)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:242)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:337)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:374)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:267)
        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:399)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1813)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:989)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, noting which lines in the trace refer to lines in your code snippet above.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just added that now.As you can see, no specific line of code is identified as the source of the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: @seekingStillness Sorry, I can't remember

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I was inflating another custom dialog view in the `onCreateView` method. Removing that solved the problem.

The `onCreateView` method is called each time `show` is invoked.
Make sure you aren't unconditionally inflating any other view in `onCreateView`.